# Movement for out-of-bound objects, canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I have a space ship in a canvas. It has velocities, `ship.vx` and `ship.vy`. When it's 30px away from the canvas  borders I set `ship.vx` & `ship.vy` to `0` and move the background objects in ship's opposite direction. At this moment the ship is stuck at a point. That's all good. Now if I try to move it left-right(`stuck at top/bottom`) or top-down(`stuck at left/right`) it doesn't since it is stuck in the point where `vx` & `vy` are set to `0`.

If i accelerate in it's opposite direction it takes like 5 seconds to pick it's velocity (around 2), so it's basically at the same point for 5 seconds.

I tried not to set `vy` to `0` when out of x-axis and vice-versa but the ship keeps moving slowly in the other axis.

So what i'm trying to achieve is the ship'll get stuck when it's 30 px from border, but if i try to move or accelerate in other 3 directions it'll pretend as if it's not stuck.

Any of you know any mechanisms?
Thanks.

```
function stuckShip(){
    if(
                (ship.x - ship.width < 0)  || 
                (ship.x + ship.width > w)  ||
                (ship.y + ship.height > h) ||
                (ship.y - ship.height < 0))
              {
        ship.vx = 0;
        ship.vy = 0;
     }

}


function againAndAgain(){
    var angle = ship.rotation;

    var x = Math.cos(angle);
    var y = Math.sin(angle);        

    var ax = x*thrust,
        ay = y*thrust;

    ship.vx += ax;
    ship.vy += ay;

            stuckShip();
            ship.draw(context);

}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 38:
            thrust = 0.35;
        break;
        case 37:
            ship.rotation -= 3;
        break;
        case 39:
            ship.rotation += 3;
        break;


    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's likely people will be able to help you without seeing the code that handles `ship.vx` and `ship.vy`, shifts to moving background objects instead, and handles responding to vector changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha ha, simple, just set ship's position to 31px from border,

```
if(ship.x <= 30){
   ship.x = 30 + 1;
}
```

What it does is, when the ship is 30px from the left, it'll set `ship.x` to 31, so it'll never be stuck, just swinging 1px back and forth. i am not sure if it's a perfect solution, but it doesn't pull back the  ship for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the velocity of an object based on it's position on the screen for display-purposes is never the best idea.
Often you use Parent-based systems, so you have one main-container and all objects (including the ship) are child to that container and move relatively to the main-container. Now you can update the container's position, if the ship's global position is in that 30px-band, to make it "lock" on the edge of the screen.

Comment: i've added my code, plz have a look. And you mean to use more canvases?

Comment: No, I mean using the concept of a Container-based Display-List: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html - if you don't have this implemented currently, this could mean some work for you, but I'd say its worth it. What framework do you use?

Comment: i haven't used any framework. it's my first game, just plain js. thanks for the link, i'm heading there..

Comment: Okay wow :) - I bet you are learning a LOT by working directly on canvas! It's a good excercise. But I would still reccomend you to use a framework like EaselJS or KineticJS. (their both good, I personally prefer EaselJS) - What they will do, is to take care of all the drawing operations, e.g.: You just say: `myShip = new Bitmap('assets/ship.png'); myShip.x = 500; myShip.y = 300; stage.addChild(myShip);` ..and then the framework will do the rest (this is a simplified example). Check out this link: http://createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

Comment: Atually @olsn canvas is not that difficult at all. The code you just listed in your comment is pretty standard for doing anything with canvas w/o using a framework. Hes not having issues with the rendering part, his issue is more with velocity based movement.

Comment: @Loktar I agree that Canvas is not that difficult. But Canvas does not come with a native Display-List implementation, and for purposes like his' the easiest way (imho) is structuring the assets/sprites in a display-list. - And why use a plain Canvas if there are already good frameworks that one can use.